# Get parameters from web_sys::File in rust

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-wasm, web-sys

I'm sending a FileList from JavaScript and trying to read the parameters of the specific file from the list, like the file name but I'm getting the error:`method not found in Option<web_sys::File>` (I'have tried different variants to call the getter methods of the File like defined in the [web-sys doc](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.File.html) but no success).

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_file_list_detail(files : web_sys::FileList) -> Option<web_sys::File> {
    let first_file = files.get(1);
    log!("Test console log from rust {:?}=",first_file.name()); //this is not working
    return first_file;
}
```

I added the `File` and `FileList` in Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3"
features = [
    "HtmlInputElement",
    "FileList",
    "File",
    "console"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`files.get(1)`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.FileList.html#method.get) returns `Option<File>` which could be either [`None` or `Some(File)` variant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/option/enum.Option.html). You can use `match` statement to match these variants and take actions accordingly.

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_file_list_detail(files : web_sys::FileList) -> Option<web_sys::File> {
    let first_file = files.get(1);
    match first_file {
        Some(ref file) => {
            log!("Test console log from rust {:?}=",file.name());
        },
        None => {
            log!("file is Missing")
        }
    }
    
    return first_file;
}
```